# How would a society evolve if there were huge golems roaming around?

Tags: society, geopolitics

In some world, the creatures that came before humans made some huge golems, about 100 meters (a bit under 330ft) tall, and eventually disappeared, leaving the golems behind. How would human societies evolve around the fact that those creatures are walking around? Feel free to consider any period of time up to near future with space exploration and stuff.

- Golems appeared far before humans. They were already old when dinosaurs became a thing.
- Their shape is humanoid without distinctive features, but still looks and feels like an animated pile of rock.
- They are indestructible by anything that humans have come up with and strong enough that no wall or chain can change their roaming.
- They feel what's happening to them, so if someone tries to build anything on them they'll shrug it off like a bug. A couple of humans with tents can be tolerated if they don't try to "mine" the golem. No chipping or heavy structures.
- Their speed is about 1-2 meters (about 5ft) per second so a human can catch up and potentially climb without any problems.
- They don't care much if something in their way. If there's a city, they'll walk over it, smashing whatever is in their path. If there is a wall about as tall as the golem itself, it gets one or two punches until it breaks. If nothing happened, the golem just tries to climb over it or walk around if it looks faster than climbing. Same thing with pits: jumps over it or walks around (or jumps down and climbs out on the other side). In case of lakes and oceans the golem will just walk like the water is not there.
- When two of these golems are about to bump into each other, they do some sort of "high five" and change their path's angle to avoid bumping. If they are out of the "high five" range they ignore each other.
- There are enough of them that most people can claim that they have seen one (or at least they are not a myth to everybody).
- If a scout reports that a golem is on its way, it's almost guaranteed that it will pass on a predefined path, save for a "high five" that would change the creature's path to a random degree.

How would cities and society be built with the thought that sooner or later they will crumble no matter what?

Comment: I like the question, but I suggedt you break it down i to multiple questions. At the end if the post you are asking many things at once.

Comment: You're basically asking us way too many things and most of those things are opinion based. VTCing accordingly.

Comment: The question could be safely restricted to city building, imho.

Comment: Restricted to city building and society, as requested

Comment: With a walking speed of 1,5m/s , they are slower than humans but not that much. That's 5,4 km/h.

Comment: The movement speed seems too slow for a humanoid of that size. With that speed, they would have one leg off the ground for nearly an hour between steps. I'm likely exaggerating, but the point still stands.

Comment: That's how they were designed. Human can easily outrun them, climb them and draw something in golem's forehead before it makes it's step. These are not war machines, just roamers who seemingly have no purpose but to walk and do high fives

Comment: Could you specify more on their numbers?  There's a pretty big gap between "most people can claim they've seen one," especially for a peasant who spends most of their life in a few square miles, and "they aren't a myth to everyone."  The amount of destruction they cause will be proportional to how often they cross an area.

Comment: If an average person sees a golem just once or twice in a lifetime, chances that it goes crushing through a village are ever slimmer.

Comment: There would be another science, sort of like astronomy for golems (golemonomy?) If it just walks straight unless another golem or a big enough natural obstacle is on its way, with enough geography knowledge it should be possible to predict all their trajectories, find safe spots (temporary or even permanent), etc. Could even plan building/demolishing/rebuilding accordingly (e. g. a golem is going to walk right through this skyscraper 100 years later, so we save on demolishing the building, and then could build a nice wide road where it walked).

Comment: They are way too rare to be of any much impact, as per Edwin's answer. They could be harnessed and their paths plotted and included in the weather news once the civilization reaches global comms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would humans in medieval times have adapted to giant roaming golems?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/49132/how-would-humans-in-medieval-times-have-adapted-to-giant-roaming-golems)

Comment: Are they smart enought to see that they are in a loop ? Can small things catch their attention ? Because those slow beast can be use for so manything, from transport to energy, We can even build on them.

Comment: Map the golem paths; use them as trade routes; build _around_ the paths, never _on_ them; profit

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Taking into account different historical periods is a bit tiresome, so I'll just throw my two cents here:

**Movable buildings:**

The biggest issue with your golems is that they roam the land endlessly and they have the tendency to destroy things in their way. Since the golems are probably unstoppable, the best thing your humans can do is *to make way*.
This requires living in wagons, tents, and every other kind of movable home. I'm sure the idea of tent-cities doesn't sound tempting at all, but if a golem is spotted in the distance, it would be rather trivial to "move" the tents out of its way. Or, at least, if a pair of tents gets smashed, it's not a big deal for the society as a whole (rather than having to rebuild a city periodically).

**Cheap buildings:**

A corollary idea is to make building so inexpensive that wasted homes can be rebuilt easily. Now, I'm not sure if this is someway attainable (especially at lower tech levels). Nowadays we are just starting to have [modular buildings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_building), and this could well be a thing in your world.

**Dig underneath:**

A more practical solution could be building any important thing beneath the earth, in tunnels, and make use of natural caves or such. From your question, I don't imagine your golems punching the sides of a mountain, or stomping their feet to make the ground quake on purpose.

To be fair, it would probably be difficult to have nice, comfortable tunnel cities (because humans aren't exactly equipped to live underground). Also, a random golem walking would still pose serious threats to most tunnels, so your humans would need to get good at architecture and geology fast.

A safer solution could be provided by natural caves; those have usually entrances small enough that your golems couldn't be able sneak in - unless, again, they don't usually raze mountains to the ground when they need to pass through. Caves are rarely large or frequent enough to sustain a growing population though.

**Plateau-cities:**

> They don't care much if something on their way. If there's a city - they'll walk over it, smashing whatever in it's path. If there is a wall about as tall as the golem itself - it gets one or two punches until it breaks. if nothing happened - golem just tries to climb over it or walk around if it looks faster than climbing.

So, pretty much, cities could be built over elevated areas and golems would walk around (unless they are specifically programmed to walk OVER the city. Are they such jerks?). The only issue here is the golem height - building an artificial plateau more than 100 meters high seems troublesome, but you should consider this in case you wish to make them smaller.

**Incapacitate golems?**

One thing you should consider is that, at any given moment in history, humanity WILL try to find a way to stop golems. They don't need to be destroyed, just stopped or re-routed. You mentioned that golems can climb pits, ad example, but what would happen if humans were to shower molten metal over the golem? 
I assume those golems have some sort of junctures; human would just need to block those. Assuming the constructs are not invulnerable or infinitely strong for plot reasons, sooner or later there should be a way to block them.

And lastly, my favourite:

**Build giant puppet-golems on wheels**:

Golems will change angle when seeing one of their kind, so maybe building a replica golem with wood and hay would trigger the high-five mechanism. If that's so, you can build a set of fake golems on wheels, much like siege engines, to redirect incoming golems out of your city. True enough, this would look so funny that it would make a great paradoxical fantasy, but it's your call.

Comment: I really like the "fake golem" idea - Medieval Pacific Rim, anyone?

Comment: You can fold the idea of floating cities into your Plateau. A bunch of boats lashed together in the middle of the ocean. Assuming that the boats are far enough from shore, the golem could walk underneath.

Answer (score 26):

If most people can claim to have "seen one" that's an average of one per lifetime, or an event between once every 45 to 90 years.

That's not very much.  California gets on average 15-20 earthquakes of magnitude 4 yearly.  Houston gets one bad Hurricane or rain event every 7 years, and that's an event that's 100 miles wide.  Both of these kinds of disasters impact whole cities, a Golem would just cut a path through part of the city.

And that's if the sighting actually had the Golem moving through the city.  Most sightings would have the Golem passing by a city, unless your cities cover substantially more earth than the country side.

Golem defense would be discussed, but rarely implemented, because one doesn't pay for defenses against the unlikely, unless it's a fear reaction after the event has occurred.

Comment: This - unless golems are an active everyday threat, people are just going to ignore them and go about their lives. Doesn't make for an interesting story though

Comment: This very much. Additionally, there would be areas which are divided by steep and massive enough mountains that golems never venture past that particular range.

Comment: Since people are stubborn enough to live next to active volcanoes, in hurricane hotspots and next to flooding rivers, this is probably the answer. They just build the city and rebuild it when something happens. They might even say "thank the gods it's just a golem, at least we get a warning when those are coming".

Comment: For an interesting real-world story about a city dealing with the mental trauma of an event just after it occurred.  Galveston decided (and did) raise the island 17 feet at the seawall, sloping downward behind the seawall.  Houses were lifted or their first floors buried.  I'd imagine a story of how a community reacted to that rare "once in a thousand year" golem strike might be interesting, if specific.

Comment: Not to mention it would take a golem just under a year to walk around the circumference of earth, not taking into account deviating for pit falls or mountains. Also the Earth being roughly 2/3 water would mean the likelihood of seeing one slim.

Comment: According to my calculations under assumption that golems try to visit every place on Earth roughly with the same frequency, 1-2 golems roam. This further shows that they are of little significance and could only be used as a prop in specific adventure, an edge that Indiana Jones grabs on to.

Answer (score 14):

While others are focused on surviving the roaming golems, I'm trying to imagine ways they could be exploited for profit. Once humans figured out the limit of people the golems will allow on them, they could be used for transportation. Sure, it looks like humans can't control the golem's direction, but a "driver" could send out messages to people where its heading.

Bear in mind this transformation is inferior to most ride-able animals, but its a luxury I could imagine people would go for.

Speaking of "drivers", setting up the equivalent of a lighthouse on the giants would be useful for travelers. This might be a dude with a churchbell on the giants dome or an actual lighthouse based on the era. With these convenient walking signposts, caravans could follow golems and trade with people who saw the signals.

For bonus points, imagine having the wagon tethered to the golem's waist and getting pulled along that way.

And just because no setting is complete without some darkness, some societies could use golems to execute criminals. Tie them where the golem will walk and let the seemingly divine being crush them into pepperoni with their unceasing feet. Oh, and people altering themselves to look like the golems might be a facet of some religions.

*edit-* Birds would love these things! Same with whatever plants that could live on them. I can't imagine a better system for spreading your seeds.

Comment: I like this idea, one thing golem transport has over anything else on land is it's huge capacity, we are talking about the ability to transport enough wood to build an small armada, or like the full output of almost any industry. And while it is nearly impossible to direct them, it sounds like their paths are easy enough for someone with good intel and maps to predict, so one can say that they are expecting a golem to arrive in 2 months, and further that they expect it to come within 1 km of the capital 4 months later. (I'm not so sure about a wagon, given 100m tall, hard to attach to it)

Comment: @LyndonWhite Filipa's golems seems especially temperamental about weight limits, otherwise I would've suggesting turning these wonders of supernatural nature into cruise-liners. I'm not sure how easy it would be to climb these guys at first, but it wouldn't take long before someone attached a rope ladder and some other niceties.

Comment: Ah, I missed the "No heavy structures" part. That is too bad.

Comment: They wouldn't need to travel on top of the golems. They could just sling a harness around them and let the golem pull transport vehicles.

Comment: @PinionMinion the weight limit and amount of people is like "how many flies a person can get before it notices?" if a bug bites your cheek, you'll try to shrug it off. If a hercules beetle land on your shoulder, you will feel it as well. At least that was my idea..

Answer (score 9):

Couple of points for anti-golem city defence:

- Moats. You stated the Golems would walk around a pit if deep or troublesome enough. Digging a giant moat around your entire city is a major pain, but better than rebuilding it
- Lake City - if the Golems walk under the water, they wouldn't affect a floating settlement if the water was deep enough. Floating settlements could probably move out of the way anyway
- Terrain as @Liquid said, taking advantage of natural terrain to build somewhere the Golems would avoid

Also - aside from building cheaper building, your inhabitants may just not care. There's already enough natural disasters, wars, acts of god and shoddy contractors that can destroy buildings/cities that the Golems may just be classed as natural disasters - easily seen ones at that.
They have plenty of warning, so they'll just evacuate ahead and then rebuild after it's passed. Probably do less damage than an earthquake anyway.

Comment: +1 for natural disaster comments.

Comment: People can be remarkably blasé about these things - we build cities on volcanoes, floodplains, tornado corridors - where the risk is a lot higher than some golem we can see coming 1000 miles away

Comment: I'm a huge fan of the moat idea. In our world, they are more trouble than their worth, but Fliipa's golems could justify their construction. Unfortunately, it looks like these guys are fine with climbing down and over gaps. Unless people are okay with digging grand canyons, the lake cities might be a more fitting solution.

Comment: Moats are also well handy for city defence - I suppose it would depend on exactly how deep qualifies as a "walk around" obstacle. It's easy enough to combine a moat with a wall anyway - that dirt has to go somewhere. You could also just build it around the most important city sections.

Comment: 100m deep lakes are pretty rare, but floating out of the way seems viable.

Comment: The shallowest of the 40 deepest lakes on Earth have the mean depth just above 100m, so not many lakes in the world where to build floating cities, probably.

Comment: Might want to add to your list the Golem equivalent of the Czech Hedgehog.  A structure built not to wall out the Golem, but to make it's forward progress so problematic that the Golem turned.

Answer (score 5):

Your society could exist in a nomadic Bedouin caravan existence. They're constantly on the move so as to avoid being trampled by the golems. Depending on what area they live in this could actually be a good thing because basically they would be a culture that lives off the land. Portable homes like Teepees would be the way to go.

Another idea is that your people live high up in the mountains. The golems would be too heavy to come up after them. At the bases of many mountain ridges are the smashed corpses of golems who did not survive their ascent. There are probably a lot of them trapped under rockslides, mudslides and avalanches too. Golems aren't too bright.

However, if your society is modern, just bomb 'em. I would imagine a nice barrage of artillery shelling would do the trick. Golems might be powerful, but they're just stone. Bunker Busters are pretty powerful too. A modern society could handle the problem I think.

Answer (score 3):

My first thought was floating cities. The golems would walk underneath you and cause no issues.

On land you'd build underground so the golems go over you.

Comment: 100m deep lakes are pretty rare

Comment: A floating city on a lake could just part as it goes by and rejoin after

Answer (score 3):

Gildartz is an over-powered character in the Anime - Fairy Tail. He is kind of similar to the Golems. He is not huge or anything but his magic is such that, he disintegrates anything he touches. He goes on multi-year quests, so he only returns to the city once in a few years (similar frequency as Golems?).

He is a bit scatterbrained though (most of the time), and a drunkard, so he doesn't follow the road. He simply walks in a straight line from the city gates to the Fairy Tail guild. In the process, he destroys any buildings that happen to be in his way (not intentionally, he just walks without seeing). Every time Gildartz returns to the city, the city gets half destroyed.

After this happened a few times, the city administration decided that since they could not stop Gildartz (because he is OP), they would change the city itself. So, they setup an alarm system which would alert everyone when Gildartz returns from one his quests. They also setup a city-wide magic-array, that would re-arrange the city in such way that there would be a straight path from the main city gates to the Fairy Tail guild. And the city would stay that way for the few days that Gildartz remained in the city. They would revert back to old structure once he left.

Maybe the same can be done for the Golems.

Comment: +1 for Fairy tale!

Answer (score 2):

Given that the existence of the golems places restrictions on city-building, the pace of scientific development would be slower. In general, such developments happen when people have time outside basic survival to play around with new ideas, and those places would be fewer in your world world. I'm assuming that *all* of the ideas in the other answers for fixed-location cities work satisfactorily, but they consume time and resources, and in many cases cannot be done everywhere.

A significant feature of the real world that enabled both social and scientific advancement was agriculture, which allowed us to *stop* being nomads and have a bit of free time to discover electricity. This is made worse by the fact that the better agricultural areas - large flat ones - are indefensible against the golems. I'd expect the rate of scientific and technological advancement to be significantly lower than the real world - another few thousand years between recorded history and the renaissance - and that will have several flow-on effects.

Once you get to the industrial revolution, you have even more reason to invest in large areas of land in a single place, so I'd also expect the explosive rate of technology we had then to be much slower, due to the scarcity of places that will survive golems.

The overall effect I think you'll see will be to have a few relatively isolated silos of science and culture in the few places that are able to build and maintain a fixed city, with the majority of other people living low-tech, nomadic lifestyles. It would not be unusual for the cities to have technology the nomads do not - they may have crossbows where the nomads on have spear-throwers, for example - but the cities would have limited means of sharing technology with other far-away cities, other than dedicated pilgrimages of scholars. The nomads themselves will use whatever technology they can find, but will probably not have the means to produce it themselves or improve on it further.

The cities will have to be largely independent - they will trade (and fight) with the nomads, but cannot rely on them as a source of peasant labour, because they won't stay long. There is unlikely to be a central power in any place for long - one city may conquer or ally with another, but unless they are very close they will become separate again over time.

Supply lines to support wars in far-off places will be difficult, because nomads would be happy to plunder easy supplies, and there will not be as much in the way of local villages that can be raided for "self-supporting" armies, so there would be no Alexanders or Khans in this world. Large standing armies would therefore not be very useful, so it is very likely that this is *not* Sparta.

It is highly likely that the cities and nomads conflict just as easily as trade - the cities will need large arable areas that are not easily defended (I'm assuming these areas are relatively unaffected by golems - after a golem passes, they can simply re-cultivate the area, and they will only suffer a temporary loss), and the nomads can (and probably will) raid them often. The nomads will not have a strong incentive to take the fight to the cities, since they are easy to defend, and the cities will equally not wish to pursue the nomads, since the nomads can keep running as far as they want, but the city's army is limited in its range. This means that despite the raids, war is unlikely, and trade will continue.

The cities, being so isolated, will develop fairly different cultures from one another, with strong differences in dialect and language too. The nomads are likely to be more homogenous within a large geographical area, which is likely to lead to a nomadic language being the language of trade. The nomads will tend to prefer oral histories, have stable traditions, and long memories.

Answer (score 2):

> Same thing with pits - jumps over it or walks around(or jumps down and climbs out on the other side)

In the beginning people would just move away, let the golem destroy whatever was not moveable in time, move in and rebuild. Sort of like a minor, predictable quake. I'd expect that *golemancy* would be a thing, and all religions would include golems somehow. Maybe sacrifice by golem stomping?

Then, some areas would be located where the golems don't go due to geographical features - hills too steep, or canyons. And what about swamps, or large fires?

Finally, people would start building *artificial* canyons so that golems walk around their cities.

(Also, no doubt, war campaigns would rely on disruption by golem to some extent).

With 1700-1800 technology, you could build an enclosed area between two large enough pits (once you discovered the appropriate size for such pits) so that golems start walking round and round the same areas.

Eventually I expect they'd find out some way of harnessing golem power... maybe using gigantic treadmills and cinema screens to make the golems believe they're moving.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's strictly necessary, but this would be a good excuse for building a world with advanced, modern civilizations that are completely mobile.  In our world, we associate a nomadic lifestyle with traditional, low-tech lifestyles, and smaller groups.  But could you have a million plus people somehow wandering around the world together, while enjoying a high tech lifestyle?  How do you maintain that population density without skyscrapers?  It's worth thinking about.